# Lazarus OSX Lion "Can not load Oracle client library libociei.dylib"

Tags: macos, oracle, osx-lion, lazarus

Lazarus 1.2.4 (FPC 2.6.4)
Oracle XE 11.2
Oracle Instant Client 32bit (Basic & SqlPlus)

I have been able to use the Lazarus TOracleConnection in the designer to connect on Windows 7 and CentOS Linux. When attempting to do the same in OSX Lion I get "Can not load Oracle client library libociei.dylib. Is it installed?" It is located in /Library/Oracle/instantclient_11_2.

I am able to connect and query via sqlplus on the Mac. Here is the contents of my .bash_profile (paths are accurate):

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/Library/Oracle/instantclient_11_2
TNS_ADMIN=/Library/Oracle/instantclient_11_2/network/admin
PATH=$PATH:/Library/Oracle/instantclient_11_2
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$ORACLE_HOME

export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export TNS_ADMIN
export PATH
export CLASSPATH
```

ORACLE_HOME is set to /Library/Oracle in Environment Variables

Can anyone tell why can't I connect through Lazarus running on OSX?

Comment: It looks like it's 32-bit, but is it possible it wants the 64-bit libraries? Or that it is redefining `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` itself and overwriting your settings? Also possible it's looking for a specific path, or expecting it under the application's own directory, but just guessing now really... Looks like `$ORACLE_HOME` should be `/Library/Oracle/instantclient_11_2` as well but that might not be relevant.

Comment: Could you install like mentioned in http://ronr.blogspot.nl/2013/02/oracle-client-11gr2-11203-for-apple-mac.html?q=instant+client ? I am not so sure of the effect of your ORACLE_HOME definition.

Comment: Apparently the IDE is using a different shell than Terminal. When I cd to the app path and run "open OraTest.app" it works! When I call ShowMessage(GetEnvironmentVariable('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH')) while running in the IDE it returns a null string. From Terminal it returns the correct path. Any ideas on what shell the IDE uses? My immediate workaround is to open Lazarus.app in Terminal. The designer works as advertised this way.

Comment: The shell the IDE Is started in. Do you start the IDE from a shell?

Comment: When I double click Lazarus.app from Applications in the OS GUI none of my exports from .bash_profile are recognized by Lazarus. They are recognized when opening Lazarus.app from the Terminal (bash shell?), so I'm assuming the OS GUI is running a different shell than the one the Terminal is using.

Comment: No shell in the unix sense maybe. Or not under that user. Anyway that is why the custom option (as described in my post) exists. So that you can get a path from your config, and init it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My immediate workaround is to open Lazarus.app in Terminal. The designer works as advertised this way. The resulting .app can be run successfully from /Applications.

Answer (score 1):

I'm neither knowledgable in Oracle nor OS X, so I just try to give some pointers:

Afaik the lazarus code just tries to dlopen('libociei.dylib').

So that either means

- it can't find it because the lib has a different name (I assume you checked this)
- it can't find it due to path issues  (DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH should be ok, but temporarily try to set it globally in case a spawned process doesn't receive the changed env
- it can't load it due to 32-bit vs 64-bit or other architectural reasons.
- it can't load it due to other errors. (missing dependencies, security/permissions)

One can try to initialize the oracle module directly with a custom path.

Try using unit ocidyn in the lpr and then

do a

```
initialiseOCI('/your/whatever/path/libociei.dylib'); as first line in your .lpr
```

Note: If the error changed from "is it installed?" to "is it already loaded?", you are on to something, since you managed to load it at least once. I mention this because this subtle change often goes unnoticed.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. See my additional comment above about what I found.